# What does the following sentence mean (related to grammar)

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

I saw the following sentence in an English learning book (It was an exercise and the final answer was the following sentence):

> Who would ask for help if you needed it?

What is the meaning of this sentence? Someone else asked for help and you needed help?! This sentence was not in a text and is an independent sentence.

If the sentence is not right, what will be the answer? the question is:
Who ....... for help if you ........ it? (Ask ,Need)  __> It must be completed with ask and need and the answer must be second conditional.

Comment: Could you post the entire exercise, please?

Comment: Please see [Q: Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer?s=0|1.6683)

Comment: Is there any context for this question? For example, is this a question asking about a reading passage?

Comment: This question was not in a text or etc. . Just a simple fill in the blank question. I think Blubberguy22 's answer is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence doesn't really make sense as it is asking who would ask for help for you if you needed it. It doesn't fit in many situations other than if you were incapacitated and couldn't ask for yourself. This statement was likely meant to be:

> Who would **you** ask for help if you needed it?

Which makes more sense and fits into more normal speech situations.

Comment: "Who would ask for help if you needed it?" could mean "Which bystanders would get you help if you needed it."

Comment: @user3169 That's mostly what I meant when I said if you were incapacitated.

Comment: You might add the original example with qualification so the difference is clear.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328911/usage-and-meaning-of-would-prefer-to-havepast-participle?noredirect=1#comment750418_328911

Comment: could you please answer this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328911/usage-and-meaning-of-would-prefer-to-havepast-participle?noredirect=1#comment750418_328911